# How can I make this if statement work with this condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The value of `@user.profile.age` could be something between 0 to 100(note this column is integer).
When it's `0`, I want it to display `Unknown`. Then I'd like it show actual number unless it's 0.

How can I customize this? If possible, I want it in a line.

```
@user.profile.age if !@user.profile.blank?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user.profile.age == 0 ? "Unknown" : @user.profile.age` should work.

Comment: Great! Go ahead and accept this answer so Stack Overflow can see it as closed.

Comment: I will. I need to wait 2 more mins. So please wait

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@user.profile.age > 0 ? @user.profile.age : "Unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try as following

```
(!@user.profile.try(:age) || @user.profile.try(:age)== 0 ) ? "Unknown" :  @user.profile.age
```

Answer (score 0):

If system find age is NULL or empty then your code will generate error. I hope this will work to rescue from being crash.

> ( @user.profile.age == 0 ) || ( !@user.profile.age.present? ) ?
>   "Unknown" : @user.profile.age